# How to extend ships' boundary when screen is resized Python Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to recreate the classic "Space Invaders" game and I want to allow anyone playing the game to resize their window using the box icon (restore / maximise) next to the close window button on the window. I have enabled the pygame.resizeable flag in the code. I am able to toggle the screen sizes using the box button and the background changes scale as it should. However, I am finding it a challenge to allow the ship to extend its boundary to the newly found "space".

The code is split into different modules according to their task. And so far I have the main game module, a settings module, game functions module, ship and bullets module respectively.

I have created a separate function (check_screen_resized(event,ship)) in the "game functions module" to respond to the pygame.VIDEORESIZE event.The function first toggles a "flag" (self.screen_resized = True) then sets the new resolution which is stored in the variable "screen" to self.screen_res = screen.

In the "ship module", when self.screen_resized = True, an "if" statement in the "update function" is activated to change the screen resolution. I am calling this "update" function in the main game module's while loop.
But my approach is not working. Can someone help me with this problem?

```
# MAIN GAME MODULE

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group

import game_functions as gme_func
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship


def run_game():
    """Initialise pygame, settings, ship and screen object."""
    pygame.init()

    ai_settings = Settings()
    # screen settings.
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height), pygame.RESIZABLE
    )
    pygame.display.set_icon(ai_settings.icon)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # make a ship.
    ship = Ship(screen, ai_settings)

    # store bullets in a group.
    bullets = Group()

    # the main game loop.
    while True:

        # listen to keyboard and mouse events.
        gme_func.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

        # update the ship's movement.
        ship.update()

        # update the bullet position and delete disappeared bullets.
        gme_func.update_bullets(bullets)

        # redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
        # make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        gme_func.update_screen(screen, ai_settings, ship, bullets)


run_game()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# GAME FUNCTIONS MODULE

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import sys
import pygame
from bullet import Bullet

*****


*****


def check_screen_resized(event, ship):
    """Update screen surfaces with resolution change."""
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.RESIZABLE)
    ship.screen_resized = True
    ship.screen_res = screen


def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Listen to keyboard and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        # moving the ship
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)

        # resize the game window.
        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            check_screen_resized(event, ship)


*****


*****

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# SHIP MODULE

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import pygame


class Ship:
    """A class that creates a ship for the Alien Invasion game."""

    def __init__(self, screen, ai_settings):
        """Initialise the ship and set its starting position."""
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        # load the ship image and get its rectangle.
        self.image = pygame.image.load(alien_invasion\images\ship3.png").convert_alpha()
        self.ship_rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # start each new ship at the bottom centre of the screen.
        self.ship_rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.ship_rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        # convert the centerx and centery values to decimal.
        self.centerx = float(self.ship_rect.centerx)
        self.centery = float(self.ship_rect.centery)

        # movement flags.
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False

        # screen resized flag.
        self.screen_resized = False
        self.screen_res = None

    def update(self):
        """Update the ship's position based on the movement flags."""
        if self.moving_right and self.ship_rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.centerx += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.ship_rect.left > self.screen_rect.left:
            self.centerx -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_up and self.ship_rect.top > self.screen_rect.top:
            self.centery -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_down and self.ship_rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.centery += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        # update the rectangle position from centerx and centery.
        self.ship_rect.centerx = self.centerx
        self.ship_rect.centery = self.centery

        # responding to screen resizing.
        if self.screen_resized:
            self.screen = self.screen_res

    def blit_ship(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.ship_rect)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: First, do you really want to increase the "playing field" when the display surface changes size? Maybe you want to just scale your game up to the new screen resolution. Second, you could simply pass the screen surface to the ships update function instead of storing it in an attribute, or just set the `screen` attribute directly instead of `screen_res`, or get the display surface by calling `pygame.display.get_surface()`

Comment: Could you crop some of the code out that isn't as crucial to the issue you are having? For example, keyboard events, the `Bullet` module, etc. It will make it a lot easier for others to get to the heart of your problem effectively.

Comment: @DavidSampson okay I have deleted the unwanted sections. Sorry about that,  today is the first time I am using stackoverflow to ask a question and I thought people will need the entire code.

Comment: @sloth the reason I want to change the "playing field" is if I don't, the ship is able to move all the way to the left edge of the window but when it tries to move all the way to the right edge of the window, it can't. There is a gap. I also set the starting position of the ship to the bottom of the screen. But when the window is maximised, the ship is sort of floating like 10cm from the bottom. So basically, the ship is still using the old screen resolution. I have tried your suggestions but I can't seem to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the following code is a basic snippet that starts a resizable screen and prints its current height and width. The following should work:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
# resizable screen
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,500), pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    # printing the width and height - we get the pygame.display.get_surface() object, and
    # get the width and height with the get_width() and get_height() funcs that the
    # returned obj has
    print(pygame.display.get_surface().get_width(), pygame.display.get_surface().get_height())
pygame.quit()
```

You can put this code snippet to use by getting updated variables containing the current screen width and height, thus telling you where the real border is.